# iOS and Infrared

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, infrared

Is it possible to communicate with an Infrared device (USB Infrared, TV, Mobile Phone, etc) using iOS (iPhone or iPad)?

Well, i know it's possible, since there are many remote/universal remote applications in the AppStore. I basically want to know how?

- What are the limitations and
  requirements?
- What kind of additional hardware is
  required? If it's available in the
  market?
- Which protocols should i know about?
- Which iOS libraries can help me in
  the process.

Can anyone point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any devices using IR for controllers are either wifi or have custom hardware that outputs IR signals based off of output from the device.  So without using your own hardware, I don't believe this is possible

Answer (score 1):

Infrared isn't unbuilt in iPhone. All those remote apps are wifi based.

Comment: Not all are wifi based.  Some involve remodulated or unconverted audio, via an external DSP or microcontroller chip, plus an IR module of course.

Answer (score 0):

The hardware isn't available but there is a hack you can make to the headphone socket.

http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2011/01/project-hijack-uses-iphone-audio-jack-to-make-cheap-sensors.ars?utm_source=Ars+Technica+Newsletter&utm_campaign=05bfd22285-January_21_2011_Newsletter&utm_medium=email

Answer (score 0):

There is no infrared connectivity within iOS.However there are bluetooth and wifi.Generally you can use bluetooth functionality by importing GameKit framework.Thanks