# Use infrared to detect object in ios or android device

Tags: android, ios, infrared

How to code to use infrared to detect a real object to check if exist in the IR detect range  by using ios or android device?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible because:

- It sends only, not recieves
- Very few android devices have infrared sender
- **NO** iOS devices have infrared sender
- Very few/no phones have infrared reciever

In most cases there are two links(for an instance in a TV); The sender and the reciever. Very few things have **both** IR sender and reciever.

Also see these:

[Is it possible to capture/receive IR signals in an Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17525696/is-it-possible-to-capture-receive-ir-signals-in-an-android-application?rq=1)

[iOS and Infrared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476207/ios-and-infrared?rq=1)

[Can iPhone camera see infrared light?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28011609/can-iphone-camera-see-infrared-light?rq=1)